# Signal R client event handler not invoked despite receiving message from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net-core, websocket, signalr

I have already tried all possible trouble shooting for this. The problem is occuring with a single event handler. the messsage is received from serverside. This i confirmed in the network tab, but the event handler is not invoked and no error is thrown.

```
objConnection.on("FileTransferAccepted", (res) => {
          setTransferStatus(true);
});
```

This is received in the browser

[image]

I have also confirmed that the event handler is attached

[image]

Im stuck. cant figure out whats wrong with just this handler. tried renaming the handler still no change.

Comment: If you know the type of the received object from SignalR, I would recommend to cast it to that object and see if it will trigger the handler.

Comment: already tried. no change. nothing was triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the problem.

I created a connection  object in one page and forgot to clean up and stop the connection before navigating to another page. Here I created another connection object and updated the connection id in the db so that im reachable. But even after the component is unmounted. the earlier connection was not destroyed. And the message was received it but that object had no event handler to handle this event. All I did was close previous connection on unmount and everything started working fine.

Summary:

Solution 1: In case you have created multiple connections in different pages or components. destroy these connections by calling the "**stop()**" method on unmount. Also dont forget to update your new connection id in db.

Solution 2: dont create multiple connections for dfferent pages, use the same object throughout the app.